# Calling JavaScript function in Python Flask app runs both if and else statements

Tags: javascript, python, if-statement, flask

Im trying to call a very simple JavasScript function with if and else in a Python Flask app but dont get it working properly.
The function works when I test it with a simple setup using only a javascript-file and a index.html.

```
let changed = false;
console.log("Changed = " + changed);

function changeColor() {

    if (changed == true ) {
        document.getElementById("bg1").style.backgroundColor = "red";
        changed = false;
        console.log("Changed to red (Changed = " + changed + ")");
    } else {
        document.getElementById("bg1").style.backgroundColor = "green";
        changed = true;
        console.log("Changed to green (Changed = " + changed + ")");
    }  
};
```

This is what it looks like when I test it outside my Flask-app:
[image]

And this is what i looks like when I run it inside my Flask-app:
[image]

For some reason, it runs both the if and else statement.

If I run call the function from the Console in my Flask app, it works.
[image]

To call the function in my Flask app, I use `onclick="changeColor()"`.

```
<ul class="list-group">
  {% for item in RecepieIngredients.query.filter_by(recepie_id = picked_recepie.id) %}
  <li class="list-group-item" id="bg{{ item.id }}"  >
    <div class="form-check" onclick="changeColor()">
      <input class="form-check-input me-2" type="checkbox" value="" id="{{ item.id }}">
      <label class="form-check-label stretched-link" for="{{ item.id }}">
      {% if item.amount % 1 == 0 %}
        {{ "%.0f"|format(item.amount|float) }} {{ item.unit }} {{ item.ingredient }}
      {% else %}
        {{ item.amount }} {{ item.unit }} {{ item.ingredient }}
      {% endif %}
      </label>
    </div>
  </li>
  {% endfor %}           
</ul>
```

There are probably different and better ways of accomplishing what I'm trying to do. And I usually just move on when I hit this kind of obsticle that's above my level of knowlage. But this time, I realy want to understand the concept :). And I cant find anything when googling.

Thanks!

EDIT:
Thanks for the input. With a push in the right direction I figured it out. I haven't tried your meathod mplugjan but will try that as well.

Shortly after I figured it out I ran into another problem with HTMLCollection. But I manage to fix that as well and not I got dynamic UL lists that' clickable.

Here the script to handle the HTMLCollection and the function.

```
let instructionsCollection = document.getElementsByClassName("instructions");
for (let i = 0; i < instructionsCollection.length; i++) {
    for (v = 0; v <= instructionsCollection.item(i).childElementCount - 1; v++) {
        instructionsCollection.item(i).children[v].addEventListener("click", stepChangeColor);
    }
}


function stepChangeColor() {
    if (document.getElementById(this.id).style.backgroundColor != stepDoneBackgroundColor) {
        document.getElementById(this.id).style.color = stepDoneTextColor;
        document.getElementById(this.id).style.backgroundColor = stepDoneBackgroundColor;
    } else {
        document.getElementById(this.id).style.color = stepDefaultTextColor;
        document.getElementById(this.id).style.backgroundColor = stepDefaultDoneBackgroundColor;
    }
    console.log("Step clicked: " + this.id);
}
```

Comment: `it runs both the if and else statement` impossible unless `changeColor` is called twice of course - which is clearly happening since `changed to green` is logged first, which is the else statements, so for `changed to red` to be logged afterwards clearly shows that the function is called a second time

Comment: Also, why are you adding onclick to the `DIV`? One thing to check in `changeColor`, `console.log(event?.target?.nodeName)`

Comment: Alright, yes its obv called tiwce and the problem seams to be where I put onclick.

I wanted to make it so that when I click that row in my UL, it turned green, but it seams that's completly the wrong way of doing it. 

I'll keep learning and try different ways.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Simple case of delegating

Set a style  `.green {background-color:green; }`

I assume you want to check and uncheck and change colour at the same time

```js
document.querySelector(".list-group").addEventListener("click", (e) => {
  const tgt = e.target.closest("li.list-group-item"); // make sure we clicked inside a list group item
  if (!tgt) return; // if not, return
  const checkbox = tgt.querySelector(".form-check-input");
  const checked = checkbox.checked;
  checkbox.checked = !checked
  tgt.classList.toggle("green", !checked);
});
```

```css
.green {
  background-color: green;
}
```

```html
<ul class="list-group">
  <li class="list-group-item" id="bg{{ item.id }}">
    <div class="form-check">
      <input class="form-check-input me-2" type="checkbox" value="" id="{{ item.id }}">
      <label class="form-check-label stretched-link" for="{{ item.id }}">
      </label>
    </div>
  </li>
  <li class="list-group-item" id="bg{{ item.id }}">
    <div class="form-check">
      <input class="form-check-input me-2" type="checkbox" value="" id="{{ item.id }}">
      <label class="form-check-label stretched-link" for="{{ item.id }}">
      </label>
    </div>
  </li>
  <li class="list-group-item" id="bg{{ item.id }}">
    <div class="form-check">
      <input class="form-check-input me-2" type="checkbox" value="" id="{{ item.id }}">
      <label class="form-check-label stretched-link" for="{{ item.id }}">
      </label>
    </div>
  </li>
</ul>
```